# Why is Chef kitchen create failing to validate my AWS key?

Tags: macos, ssh, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm having a problem with kitchen create. Says its failing to validate the provided access credentials. No idea why.

---

```
--------------
>>>>>> ------Exception-------

>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed

>>>>>> Message: 1 actions failed.

>>>>>> Failed to complete #create action: [AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials] on default-centos-72

>>>>>> ----------------------

>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details

>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

---

I am running on macosx terminal with an EC2 AWS instance using CentOS 7 -x86_64- - with Updates HVM-1602-AutogenByAWSMP-

all ports are open 80, 22 and 443

key is the access key for AWS and has been used prior with success.

.kitchen.yml is as follows:

---

```
---

driver:

name: ec2

aws_ssh_key_id: learn-chef

region: us-west-2

availability_zone: c

subnet_id: subnet-c6bfa69e

instance_type: t2.micro

image_id: ami-d2c924b2

security_group_ids: sg-1af04361

retryable_tries: 120

provisioner:

name: chef_zero

verifier:

name: inspec

transport:

ssh_key: /Users/gavindevops/.ssh/GavinChefKey.pem

platforms:

- name: centos-7.2

suites:

- name: default

run_list:

- recipe[learn_chef_httpd::default]

verifier:

inspec_tests:

- test/smoke/default

attributes:
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally figured it out. I'm stupid. I didn't update my credentials file in /root/.aws/credentials to have my access and secret keys.

Egg and my face, were in alignment.